# How to access a file in windows using Spark and winutils?

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark on windows using `winutils`.
In spark shell in trying to load a csv file, but it says `Path does not exist`, i.e. I have a file at location **E:/data.csv**.
I am executing:

```
scala> val df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("E:\\data.csv")
```

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/E:/data.csv;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:558)
```

I cant figure out why is it appending a **"/E:"**, whereas it should have been only **E:**
How should I access the file?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am able to read the file as below 
val input = spark.sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true")
      .option("delimiter", ";").option("quoteAll","true").option("inferSchema","false").load("C:/Work/test.csv").toDF()